# Neo4j creating multiple nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I'm trying to create a family. On my webapp a user fills out his family details. This includes 2 parents and 3 siblings.

How do I create all 6 nodes and relationships simultaneously?

I see you can create a node, relationship and another node with the following:

`CREATE (p:Person {name: "Me"})-[:HAS_SIBLING]->(:Sibling {name: "John"})`

But nothing suggests to me that this will extend beyond 2 relationships:

```
CREATE  (:Sibling {name: "Jeff"})<-[:HAS_SIBLING]-
        (p:Person {name: "Me"})-[:HAS_SIBLING]->
        (:Sibling {name: "John"})
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want get. It would be better if you show an example of the data and the desired result of a query.

Comment: @stdob-- I'm hoping to create a node with 5 relationships and a node at the end of each relationship. Not sure what is the most optimal way to create that? Right now I'm just doing something like: 
`CREATE (p:Person {name: "ME"}), (s:Sibling {name:"Jeff"}), (p)-[:HAS_SIBLING]->(s), ...repeat for each sibling or parent relationship`. It works but not sure if that is the correct way?

Comment: I think that is quite correct way. But you should pay attention to the use `MERGE` statement to avoid create extra nodes. And it is not very clear why you use for some nodes the label `Sibling` instead of `Person` the more you already have a relationship `HAS_SIBLING`?

Comment: @stdob-- Yea sorry about the label sibling, my example isn't actually a family and I wrote the query quickly wihtout thinking. Mostly I was wondering about the proper way to do multiple node and relationship creation at the same time. Thanks for your clarification!